# I want to change URL in same window or modify the url

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to change URL from < support.tomtom.com/app > to < support.tomtom.com/app/contact > in the same window.

I am using Selenium web driver.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
driver.navigate().to("https://support.tomtom.com/app/contact/")
```

but like Thomas said, please read that link before asking a question

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this command but it was not working. I made few changes in the program itself and it works.  maybe there was some other issue.
And yes I will post my question in a proper format next time.